# Websocket connection - no valid credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to create a simple nodejs application that connects to the pathofexile.com/trade api.

The problem with this API is that is that you cannot use it unless you're logged in on the main website (my code works in the browser, but I'm trying to make it into a desktop application). There are several other applications that solves this issue by creating a session ID cookie with a users session ID (ID that you can get by logging in to the website). Unfortunately the documentation of the API is very limited and I havn't been able to find any information on how I can *create/use* the cookie as needed.

If I try to connect to the websocket, without being logged in to the main pathofexile website, I get the following error:

```
VM58:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/live/Metamorph/e602K4cL' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
```

I've tried using my sessionID to create a cookie like this by using the built in features in node:

```
const cookie = { name: 'POESESSID', value: '3acbf42fb842aasdqwe1a0c355f',domain: 
'.pathofexile.com' }
  session.defaultSession.cookies.set(cookie)
.then(() => {
// success
  console.log("Cookie set (?)")
}, (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I'm very unfamiliar with websockets (only started playing around with any of this a few days ago by accident), and I'm even less familiar with how websockets access and get data from cookies.

I've tried other modules like npm cookie-parser, npm request and npm needle to no avail.

The closest I've gotten to an answer is from a one year old reddit post where the user used C# to get this to work.

This is the code used in that example:

```
// Setup HTTP connection
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
cookieContainer.Add(composeUrl, new Cookie("POESESSID", sessionId));
handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

If someone could help shine some light on this I'd be very appreciative. I understand that this question is incredibly niche and perhaps I'm asking it in the wrong forum, but I really don't know where to turn.

Appreciate any help!
//Alex

Comment: You will have to examine what the browser application uses for tracking authentication and then you will have to simulate that in your desktop app, probably by logging in to the site with the appropriate http post and retaining the credentials that come back from that (however they are done).

Comment: I'm not really sure what this means.

The only way I've gotten it to work, without logging in, is by adding the cookie manually in the chrome Application tab. After that is done it works, for that session atleast. 

I think I need a way to create a cookie that looks like this:

POESESSID=[MYSESSIONID] which in turn needs to have it's domain set to '.pathofexile.com'.

Thanks for your reply tho! If you have any further suggestions on how I can try to track the authentication that'd be amazing!

Comment: You said it works in the browser.  So, you have to go reverse engineer HOW it works in the browser.  Examine the login request in the network tab of the Chrome debugger.  See exactly what is sent on what type of request and exactly what it returns. Examine the webSocket connection request and see exactly what is sent with it.  Then, you will have to execute both of these operations in your desktop app.  You will have to login, get the credentials that come back from that (probably a cookie) and use that cookie with your webSocket connection.  This is reverse engineering.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed enter assuming it would give me a linebreak!


I've tried looking at the Network tab in chrome, but I can't find a pattern at all.

Here is a screenshot:
https://imgur.com/q8r89W4

Left one is when I'm not logged in, right is when I'm logged in.


I have no idea what I'm looking at or for to be honest hehe..

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that the sessionid actually persists for a whole month. So its not something i need to activly get, the ID I already have. So I assume that the only thing I need is to have created the cookie before I try to open the websocket.

Comment: You mean you're going to try to copy the cookie out of the browser and use that with your webSocket?  Yes, you could do that if the site doesn't implement any protections against that and the cookie persists for the duration of your need.  You can use the network tab in Chrome to see the EXACT HTTP request that initiates the webSocket connection and copy those headers exactly.

Comment: Maybe the webSocket sends authentication credentials AFTER it connects?  I can't really read those screen shots (text too small).